# SQL query to full / differential backup in schedule.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup, schedule

I'm running SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

I need to create full and differential backups.

Full - in monday 
Differential - in wednesday

I can't find sql query to do this. I know that is possible to schedule job in software, but i need query . 
Is that possible too?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`BACKUP DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) documentation provided by Microsoft. This page should give you sufficient information to create the queries required to take full and differential database backups.

You may also want to look into [Maintenance Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx), a feature that ships with SQL Server. This provides you with a GUI to easily create and schedule backups as well as other common maintenance tasks.

Comment: I know about GUI, but i need Transact-SQL Query.

Comment: @TomekMałecki Were you able to work out the T-SQL necessary to create your backups?

Comment: That was a stupid task from university teacher. That is not make sense when you have GUI.